# Get info form phpdom

Tags: php, html, curl

I am trying to get information using curl.

Approximately I got all information, but I need to get information individually.

For example I am getting a td text using curl.

here is the td content

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qhv787d2/)

I need to extract text "my info", myinfo href link and last page number.

How i can do this?

here is my code which i am using in curl

```
 $nodes = $finder->evaluate('//td[contains(text(), "") and starts-with(@id, "td_threadtitle_") ]');
        foreach ($nodes as $node) 
            {
        $innerHTML = trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
        $fh = fopen("test.html", 'w'); // we create the file, notice the 'w'. This is to be able to write to the file once.
        //writing response in newly created file
        fwrite($fh, $node->c14n()); // here we write the data to the file.
        fclose($fh);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My info

```
(//td[starts-with(@id, "td_threadtitle_") ]//a[1]/text())[1]
```

It's href

```
(//td[starts-with(@id, "td_threadtitle_") ]//a)[1]/@href
```

Last page number

```
substring-after(//td[starts-with(@id, "td_threadtitle_") ]//a[. = "Last Page"]/@href, "page=")
```

Comment: I Solved this, can you please check My answer is ok or not? But its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it's according to my requirement.

Please tell me is this ok or not?

```
    $options = $node->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $post_message_id=$node->getAttribute('id');

        foreach($options as $option) {
             $value = $option->getAttribute('id');

            if($value!=""){
                print_r( $option->getAttribute('href'));
                echo "\n";
                print_r( $option->textContent);
                echo "\n";
                print_r($options->item(($options->length)-1)->getAttribute('href'));
                echo "\n";
            }

        }
```